# Customize organic search sources

Tags: google-analytics

I want to exclude some of the organic search traffic from some websites. Those websites are not included in "Organic Search Sources", but still appear in organic channel traffic. Below are the websites that appear in organic search,

rakuten
so.com
sogou
startsiden

Thanks,
Magesh

Comment: "I want to exclude some of the organic search" - I'm pretty sure that is not what you want. Do you mean you want this attributed to another channel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with refferal exclusions:

[All the info you need is in the Google Documentation.](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795830?hl=en)

Be aware that testing this should be done in realtime reports, because old data is never deleted if you change things in your view.

Comment: But how does it affect if i add those sites in referral exclusion list. It still shows up in organic traffic.

Comment: If i add the sites in referral exclusion list, it will affect only in referral reports. My question is i want to exclude particular domains from search traffic and i want those domains to come in referral reports.